# Use linmod in a function scope

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm writing a function that uses `linmod` but I get many undefined variables errors. Those variables are defined in the function scope but I guess `linmod` wants them in the global workspace. In `sim` you can set the `SrcWorkspace` to `current` and use it in a function scope. Is there something similar for `linmod`?

Comment: Not that I know of. How are the variables defined? By a script or loading a MAT file? It might be easier (although not very efficient) to generate those variables in the base workspace using `evalin` (possibly one of the few legitimate uses of `eval` or `evalin`).

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving should have a hyperlink to the line of code (most likely in the function dlinmod) where the error occurs.  This will show that the model is being executed using an feval statement (not sim).  Hence the model will be looking in the Model Workspace, then the Base Workspace for its parameters.

You'll need to set up your model to get its data from one of those 2 locations.